# httpRequest se ejecuta al final de las demas instrucciones

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

El problema es este:
Estoy validando el codigo RDA, necesito hacer una peticion al servidor para que me diga si ese codigo ya esta registrado o no. El responseText me devuelve 0 si no encuentra coincidencias en la base de datos o !=0 si encuentra coincidencias.
El httpRequest devuelve los valores correctos, con esos valores yo cambio el valor de una variable global a 0 o 1 y luego con esa variable global valido con un if para devoler true o false.
El problema es que primero ejecuta el   if(global == 0)  y luego recien ejecuta el httpRequest, entonces mi variable global no cambia siempre se mantiene en cero.

Quiero que se ejecute primero el httpRequest, y luego se realize la consulta IF, pero hace todo lo contrario, primero ejecuta el IF y luego recien hace la consulta HttpRequest

```js
var global = 0;

    var RDA = document.getElementById('RDA').value;

    httpRequest(
                `http://localhost:8080/sitios%20web/Murphy/Validaciones/validarRDA/${RDA}`,
                function () {
                    var existente = this.responseText;
                    if(existente == 0){
                        console.log("existen "+ existente);
                        console.log("la variable global de mantienteen " +global);
                        global=0;
                    }else{
                        console.log("existe 1" + existente);
                        console.log("la variable global cambia a  1");
                        global=1;
                    }
                })
                    
    if(global == 0){
        console.log("funciona, la variable es " + global);
    }else{
        console.log("al fin la variable es "+ global)   ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Las peticiones http son asíncronas eso significa que el programa no espera a que finalicen para seguir ejecutándose. Una solución sencilla es mover la validación y ponerla dentro de la función callback del `httpRequest`

```
httpRequest(
  `http://localhost:8080/sitios%20web/Murphy/Validaciones/validarRDA/${RDA}`,
  function () {
    var existente = this.responseText;
    if (existente == 0) {
      console.log("existen " + existente);
      console.log("la variable global de mantienteen " + global);
      global = 0;
    } else {
      console.log("existe 1" + existente);
      console.log("la variable global cambia a  1");
      global = 1;
    }

    // validación dentro del callback
    // de la petición http
    if (global == 0) {
      console.log("funciona, la variable es " + global);
    } else {
      console.log("al fin la variable es " + global);
    }
  }
);
```

**Actualización**

Se puede envolver `httpRequest()` dentro de una función asíncrona que devuelve una promesa. De esa forma se puede usar el operador `await` para que la ejecución del código sea secuencial.  **Nota**: la función asíncrona `peticionHttp()` debe llamarse dentro de otra función asíncrona.

```
async peticionHttp() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      httpRequest(
        `http://localhost:8080/sitios%20web/Murphy/Validaciones/validarRDA/${RDA}`,
        function() {
          var existente = this.responseText;
          if (existente == 0) {
            console.log("existen " + existente);
            console.log("la variable global de mantienteen " + global);
            global = 0;

            resolve(true);

          } else {
            console.log("existe 1" + existente);
            console.log("la variable global cambia a  1");
            global = 1;

            resolve(false);
          }
        }
      );
    });

  }
```

Ejecutar la función `peticionHttp()`

```
// la función debe ser asíncrona
async validarDocente(){

  // resto del código
  let resultado = await peticionHttp();
        
  if(resultado){
            
  }else{
            
  }

}
```

**Actualización 2**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "hello",
  template: `
    <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <input type="text" name="nombre" />
      <input type="submit" value="enviar" />
    </form>
  `
})
export class HelloComponent {
  async onSubmit() {
    let resultado = await this.validarDocente();

    if (resultado) {
      console.log("datos validos serán enviando");
    } else {
      console.log("datos no validos no serán enviados");
    }
  }

  async validarDocente() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(true);
      }, 2000);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Verás. En realidad estoy haciendo una validación con un "Onsubmit" en mi formulario. Todo el código que subí está dentro de una función llamada 'validarDocente', necesito que dentro de esta función, se haga la consulta con el httpRequest, para verificar la existencia y que la función httpRequest me devuelva un true o false dependiendo del número de registros encontrados.Estaba intentando hacerlo con una variable global que cambie de valor dependiendo el resultado del httpRequest, y luego con esa variable hacer un If para devolver el true o false.

Comment: O si conoces alguna forma de lograr que mi función httpRequest me retorne el true o false muchísimo mejor. O en su defecto, alguna forma de que se espere a finalizar todo el httpRequest antes de continuar ejecutando el resto.

Comment: Agregué una actualización usando promesas para lograr un código secuencial.

Comment: Perfecto, implemente la promesa y funciono perfecto, pero tengo otro problema. El "Onsubmit" en mi formulario, no acepta la funcion "validarDocente()" por que esta es asincrona. El codigo y la idea de retornarlo como una promesa esta perfecto, funciona y devuelve lo esperado, el problema es que debo convertir mi funcion "validarDocente" en una funcion asincrona y el formulario no ejecuta la funcion. Se supone que al yo devolverle un false, el formulario no deberia enviarse, pero al ser ahora una funcion asincrona se estan enviando los datos aunque yo devuelva false.

Comment: Entonces la función `onSubmit()` deber ser asíncrona también para poder hacer `await this.validarDocente();`. Agregué un ejemplo en la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente tengo un campo de mi formulario del que quiero validar su existencia. Si ya esta registrado o no. El codigo que tengo funciona, el problema es que como es una funcion asincrona, cuando devuelvo el "false" no se detiene

nuevoDocente/RegistrarDocente" method="POST"

```js
function peticionHttp(RDA) {
    return new Promise((resolve)=>{
    httpRequest(`http://localhost:8080/sitios%20web/Murphy/Validaciones/validarRDA/${RDA}`,
            function () {
                var existente = this.responseText;
                if(existente == 0){
                    resolve(true);
                }else{
                    resolve (false);
            }
        })
    })
}


async function validacionDocente(){

var RDA = document.getElementById('RDA').value;


    let resultado = await peticionHttp(RDA)

    if(resultado == true ){
        console.log("El RDA no esta registrado. RDA valido");
    }else{
        console.log("El RDA ya esta registrado, RDA invalido, ingrese otro");
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<form action="<?php echo constant('URL') ?>nuevoDocente/RegistrarDocente" method="POST" id="formDocente"
 onsubmit="return validacionDocente();">
 //Este es el formulario, el onsubmit deberia impedir que se envien los datos, pero como la funcion a la que apunta es asincrona, los datos se siguen enviando
 
  <div>
  //este es el dato que quiero validar.
  <input type='number' id='RDA' name='RDA'>
  <div id="respuestaRDA"></div>
  <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
  </div>
```